# Derive the transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, active-filter, passive-filter

I am trying to use the short-cut method to derive V0/V1. My answer seems to be wrong may someone please attempt to do.

I first looked at the node between R1 and R0 then went to the node connected to V-.
[image: this image is from my course material I do not know how to reference it]

My first attempt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ud62.jpg

My second attempt:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Can you rotate the image correctly? If that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: ok, since you do not know for sure if your answer is right or wrong, then please add your work and your answer to your post

Comment: Please provide your solutions first so we can comment on them.

Comment: You're first equation has a mistake in it. It appears to be the KCL equation for the node X, but for that there are three currents which need to considered: the currents through R1, C1 and R0. So the equation should have terms for each of these.

Comment: OW WOW thanks Erik !!  I totally did not see that let me attempt again.

Comment: 2nd node equation is wrong too.

Comment: At s=0 Av=-R2/(R0+R1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a concept of *outflowing* and *inflowing* currents, which is how Spice programs develop their matrices as well, when developing my KCL equations. I place the first on the left side and the second on the right side. These, of course, must equal each other.

I present this as an alternative for you to consider. Traditional teaching tells you to make decisions about voltage differences across a component. But this is fraught with greater difficulties in getting the sign right each time. And too many people, too many times, get it wrong. Or, at least, don't get it consistently right. Even I don't get it consistently right and I've been doing it for decades. Please see the KCL Addendum below for further discussion.

Your nodal equations are then:

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rccc}
      {V_A:}\vphantom{\frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}}\\\\
      {V_{-}:}\vphantom{\frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}}\\\\
      {V_O:}\vphantom{\frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
     \begin{array}{r}
          \frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{A}}{R_1} + \frac{V_{A}}{\frac1{s\,C_1}}\\\\
          \frac{V_{-}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{-}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{-}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}\\\\
          \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}
     \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
      &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}}\\\\
      &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}}\\\\
      &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
     \begin{array}{l}
          \frac{V_{-}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{I}}{R_1} +  \frac{0\:\text{V}}{\frac1{s\,C_1}}\\\\
          \frac{V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}\\\\
          \frac{V_{-}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{-}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}+I_O
     \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

Re-arranging them in your order form:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{-}-V_{A}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{I}-V_{A}}{R_1} +  \frac{0\:\text{V}-V_{A}}{\frac1{s\,C_1}}&= 0\:\text{A}\\\\
\frac{V_{A}-V_{-}}{R_0} + \frac{V_{O}-V_{-}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{O}-V_{-}}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}&= 0\:\text{A}\\\\
\frac{V_{-}-V_O}{R_2} + \frac{V_{-}-V_O}{\frac1{s\,C_2}}&= -I_O
\end{align*}$$

(I feel the outflowing/inflowing arrangement appears cleaner. It's easy to read and understand. The traditional approach is a bit *sign-ridden* in the numerators and, I think, this *begs* for *sign errors*: no matter how good you get at it. If you agree, please leave the old method behind as soon as you are allowed to do so and never come back to it.)

---

Before looking at the resulting answer, let's take a moment to examine your circuit.

It's pretty easy to see that \$V_I\$ is voltage source and that \$V_{-}\$ is, at least, a *virtual* voltage source (at ground.) So this means that \$R_0\$ and \$R_1\$ will make up a voltage divider with an equivalent Thevenin impedance: \$R_0\mid\mid R_1\$. This interacts with \$C_1\$ and therefore you should expect to find a time constant, \$\tau_{_1}=\left(R_0\mid\mid R_1\right)C_1\$, showing up somewhere in the answer.

It's also pretty easy to see that \$R_2\$ and \$C_2\$ should make up another time constant, \$\tau_{_2}=R_2 C_2\$, showing up somewhere else in your answer.

---

Solving the above for \$V_A\$, \$V_O\$, and \$I_O\$ (the output current of the opamp), then setting \$V_{-}=0\:\text{V}\$, I get \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\sqrt{\frac{R_0+R_1}{R_0+R_2}\,\cdot\,\tau_{_1}\,\cdot\,\tau_{_2}}}\$, \$\zeta=\frac1{2\,\omega_{_0}}\cdot\left(\frac1{\tau_{_1}}+\frac1{\tau_{_2}}\right)\$, and \$A=-\frac{R_2}{R_0+R_1}\$ for the standard 2nd order low-pass form of \$\mathcal{H}=\frac{V_O}{V_I}=A\cdot \frac{\omega_{_0}^2}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}\,s+\omega_{_0}^2}\$.

Note that the expected values, \$\tau_{_1}\$ and \$\tau_{_2}\$, showed up, as expected. These are the kinds of quick cross-checks that are worth a moment, just to make sure you didn't goof up somewhere in your process.

### KCL Addendum

The KCL equations may appear to treat node voltages as if they don't have to be differences, but can be absolute values. However, that's not really the case here. In fact, I'm just using superposition (which is easily seen once you've really had the concepts deepened into you.) This is, in fact, the same technique used within Spice programs (those where I've directly looked over the code used to generate these.)

Perhaps the easiest way to imagine is that absolute voltage at a node ***spills away*** from that node ***through*** the available paths. But also that absolute voltages ***spill into*** that node from surrounding nodes through those same paths. So long as you treat them all as absolute values, the result is the application of a simple superposition concept that results in, effectively, the potential differences controlling the result.

You can test this, easily, by rearranging the resulting equation(s), moving the right side over to the left side and then combining terms. You'll then see the usual potential differences that you expect. So it really is the same result.

The reason I very much prefer this method is that it is simple to visualize and very difficult to make mistakes. You can easily orient yourself to a node and then work out the terms for out-flowing currents for the left side of the equation. Then all you have to do is position yourself at each surrounding node and work out the terms for in-flowing currents for the right side. It's almost impossible to screw that up.

Conversely, when you are instead struggling to work out the potential differences in your mind (using the more traditionally taught method) and just write those terms, you often find yourself not entirely sure if you have the sign right as you try and add them up, correctly. I find, time and time again that not only others wind up messing up somewhere and making an uncaught mistake.. but that I also make those mistakes, as well. Even with lots of experience, you just aren't 100% sure and you often find yourself double and triple checking your work, just in case.

That doesn't ever happen, once you start using the superposition method. It just works. It just works right. It just works right each and every time. I've never, not once, screwed up. (I make typos. But not sign errors.) It's too easy to use.

So voltage spills away from a node via available paths and voltage spills into a node from nearby nodes via the same available paths. The only caveat is that a current source or sink can only flow in, or flow out, but not both directions. It's one way. So it will either appear on the out-flowing side or on the in-flowing side -- but not both sides.

This also works perfectly well with capacitors and inductors. It does turn the equation into a differential/integral equation. But that's just a technicality. It's still correct.

### Using Free Tools

I'd also like to recommend that you learn to use [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), which is freely available.

Let me show you one way you may use that tool for the above case:

```
var('vo vi r1 r0 r2 c1 c2 va vm s io') # let sympy know your variable names
zc1 = 1/s/c1                           # capacitor C1 impedance
zc2 = 1/s/c2                           # capacitor C2 impedance
zp2 = r2 / (1 + r2/zc2)                # parallel (R2 || C2) impedance
                                       # ... same as writing zc2 / (1 + zc2/r2)
eq1 = Eq( va/r1 + va/r0 + va/zc1, vi/r1 + vm/r0 )
eq2 = Eq( vm/r0 + vm/zp2, va/r0 + vo/zp2 )
eq3 = Eq( vo/zp2, vm/zp2 + io )
ans = solve( [eq1, eq2, eq3], [va, vo, io] )
tf = simplify( (ans[vo]/vi).subs({vm:0}) )
H = tf2( tf )
```

That last statement uses some code I wrote in Python (sympy requires Python) for 2nd order transfer functions to help me out when putting things into standard form:

```
def tf2( h ):
    global s, omega, zeta, P, A, N
    s, omega, zeta, P, A, N = symbols( "s omega zeta P A N")
    expr = simplify( h )
    n, d = fraction( expr )
    v = {}
    for fs in d.free_symbols: v[fs] = 1
    nc = Poly( expand( n ), s).all_coeffs()
    dc = Poly( expand( d ), s).all_coeffs()
    sgn = dc[0].subs( v )
    if sgn < 0:
        nc = Poly( expand( -n ), s).all_coeffs()
        dc = Poly( expand( -d ), s).all_coeffs()
    if len( dc ) == 3 and len( nc ) <= len( dc ):
        omegac = powdenest( sqrt( simplify( dc[2] / dc[0] ) ), force=True )
        zetac = powdenest( simplify( dc[1] / 2 / powdenest( sqrt( simplify( dc[0] * dc[2] ) ), force=True ) ), force=True )
        u = []
        for i in range( len( nc ) ):
            Av = powdenest( simplify( nc[i] / dc[len( dc ) - len( nc ) + i] ), force=True )
            if Av != 0:
                u.append( { A: Av, N: (len( nc ) - i - 1) } )
        return { omega: omegac, zeta: zetac, P: u }
```

This function is defined for me inside a file called init.sage. (I use sympy as part of [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), which is another free tool.) It is able to handle the *full* 2nd order transfer function of this very general form.

$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{H}\left(s\right)&=\frac{a_2 s^2 + a_1 s + a_0}{b_2 s^2 + b_1 s + b_0}\\\\
&=\frac{a_2 s^2}{b_2 s^2 + b_1 s + b_0}+\frac{a_1 s}{b_2 s^2 + b_1 s + b_0}+\frac{a_0}{b_2 s^2 + b_1 s + b_0}
\end{align*}$$

And turn it into one of this *standard* form:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{H}\left(s\right)&=A_2\frac{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}  { \left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2 + 2\zeta \left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right) + 1}+A_1\frac{ 2\zeta \left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)}  { \left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2 + 2\zeta \left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right) + 1} +A_0\frac1  { \left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2 + 2\zeta \left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right) + 1}\\\\
&=A_2\frac{ s^2}  { s^2 + 2\zeta\,\omega_{_0} s + \omega_{_0}^2}+A_1\frac{ 2\zeta\,\omega_{_0} s}  { s^2 + 2\zeta\,\omega_{_0} s + \omega_{_0}^2}+A_0\frac{ \omega_{_0}^2}  { s^2 + 2\zeta\,\omega_{_0} s + \omega_{_0}^2}
\end{align*}$$

So here is what I get from it:

```
H
{omega: sqrt(r0 + r1)/(sqrt(c1)*sqrt(c2)*sqrt(r0)*sqrt(r1)*sqrt(r2)),
 zeta: (c1*r0*r1/2 + c2*r0*r2/2 + c2*r1*r2/2)/(sqrt(c1)*sqrt(c2)*sqrt(r0)*sqrt(r1)*sqrt(r2)*sqrt(r0 + r1)),
 P: [{A: -r2/(r0 + r1), N: 0}]}
```

The first two shown there, *omega* and *zeta*, are common to all terms (regardless of whether there is one, two, or three of them.) The **P** part is an array. Here, it indicates the \$A\$ factors for each term and the **s**-power of the term, \$N\$. You can see that the only \$s^0\$ is present. So this is a low-pass filter.

It's true that \$\alpha=\omega_{_0}\cdot\zeta\$. So to achieve the above results for \$\zeta\$, more easily, I did this:

```
alpha = simplify( H[zeta] * H[omega] )
```

I found that \$\alpha=\frac12\left(\frac1{\tau_{_1}}+\frac1{\tau_{_2}}\right)\$. So it was then very easy to write out the result from \$\zeta=\frac{\alpha}{\omega_{_0}}\$.

Comment: The funny part is that people coming in contact with the L>R U>D rule in SPICE are baffled because they expect some personal interpretation of the meshes and directions. Yet it's precisely that consistency in choices that makes the simulators so reliable.